# get carousel image at center with prev next sliders

Tags: html, css

I'm following this example https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/half-slider/

I'm trying to get image smaller and center

I updated css to reduce size

```
min-height: 350px;
max-width: 900px;
```

But it's left bound and sliders icons are stuck to left and right
any pointers?

Comment: you have to just use `.snippet {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 350px;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

Answer (score 1):

If i not mistaken what you are asking is make image smaller and center using the example you can do like this at css change this

```css
#carouselExampleIndicators{
margin: auto;
min-height: 350px;
max-width: 900px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/RCAhiGJsUUE/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">First Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/wfh8dDlNFOk/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">Second Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/O7fzqFEfLlo/1920x1080')">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">Third Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<section class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="font-weight-light">Half Page Image Slider</h1>
    <p class="lead">The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The images in this snippet are from <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The original example is setting image by using background-image property. If you want to change the width of the image without changing the width of the carousel, just use `<img>` tag to insert images and style those  elements.

```css
.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 350px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
}

.carousel-item>img{
  max-width:900px;
  height:100%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/RCAhiGJsUUE/1920x1080"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">First Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/wfh8dDlNFOk/1920x1080"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">Second Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
      <div class="carousel-item" style="">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/O7fzqFEfLlo/1920x1080')"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3 class="display-4">Third Slide</h3>
          <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<section class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="font-weight-light">Half Page Image Slider</h1>
    <p class="lead">The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The images in this snippet are from <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one solved my issue

```
#carouselExampleIndicators{
margin: auto;
min-height: 550px;
max-width: 900px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item{
 overflow: hidden; min-height: 550px; max-width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;
}
```